# Mark last item in my ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

i build application and add files to my ListView, I want the last file added each time will emphasize so inside my Foreach statement i added `lvFiles.Items[lvFiles.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;` but in this case all the files inside my ListView emphasized and not only the last one

```
List<string> filesList

            foreach (string fileName in filesList)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
                if (checkFileCreationDate(fileInfo))
                {
                    if (editcap.isWiresharkFormat(fileInfo.FullName))
                    {
                        if (editcap.isLibpcapFormat(fileInfo.FullName))
                        {
                            addFileToListBox(fileInfo.FullName, capinfos.getFileDuration(fileInfo.FullName));
                        }
                        else if (!editcap.isLibpcapFormat(fileInfo.FullName))
                        {
                            fileToAdd = editcap.getNewFileName(fileInfo.FullName);

                            if (new FileInfo(fileToAdd).Exists && !fileInfo.Exists)
                            {
                                addFileToListBox(fileToAdd, capinfos.getFileDuration(fileInfo.FullName));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

private void addFileToListBox(string filePath, string duration)
{
    item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { new FileInfo(filePath).Name, duration, "Waiting" });
    item.Tag = new FileInfo(filePath).FullName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just put that statement after your foreach and it should work.

like:

```
foreach(var x in colY)
{
  //check file
  lvFiles.Items[lvFiles.Items.Count - 1].Selected = false;
  //add item here
  lvFiles.Items[lvFiles.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: OK but i want that my application show my while added files all the time the last file in the ListView without manually move to the end of my list

Comment: i add the files into my ListView from List<string>, see my update

Comment: @user1269592: see me edit. that should unselect the last item and then select the new item. however, i doubt this will show up at all because you seem to be doing all work in the UI thread, which will cause the UI to "freeze".

Comment: not working, i want that the focus will be all the time on the last item in the ListView while files being added

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by unselecting the previous elements and only then selecting the final one:

```
foreach (var item in lvFiles.Items)
{
    item.Selected = false;
}

lvFiles.Items[lvFiles.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
```